# Cannot run sveltekit in prod because of MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sveltekit

I am trying to use mongoDb in my sveltekit app.
Everything is fine in dev. No warnings.

I am using sveltekit node adapter

When i run `pnpm run build` i am getting circular dependencies which then break my app.

The app only breaks when ran with `node build/index.js`

The app works fine with `pnpm run preview`

Circular dependencies mention `aws` when looking in the project for it, it only appears in pnpm-lock.yaml under `/mongodb@5.1.0:` as peerDependencies.

Cirular dependencies :

```
> Using @sveltejs/adapter-node
"aws-sdk" is imported by "aws-sdk?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
"nock" is imported by "nock?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
"mock-aws-s3" is imported by "mock-aws-s3?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/rename.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor/change_stream_cursor.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-connection-string-url@2.6.0/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-connection-string-url@2.6.0/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/redact.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb-connection-string-url@2.6.0/node_modules/mongodb-connection-string-url/lib/index.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/encrypter.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/encrypter.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/connection_string.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/monitor.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@5.1.0/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/server.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/readable-stream@3.6.2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/glob@7.2.3/node_modules/glob/glob.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/glob@7.2.3/node_modules/glob/sync.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/glob@7.2.3/node_modules/glob/glob.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.10/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.10/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/pre-binding.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/@mapbox+node-pre-gyp@1.0.10/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
Circular dependency: node_modules/.pnpm/semver@7.3.8/node_modules/semver/classes/comparator.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/semver@7.3.8/node_modules/semver/classes/range.js -> node_modules/.pnpm/semver@7.3.8/node_modules/semver/classes/comparator.js
```

Errors in runtime when i go to a page where an action uses mongodb:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mock-aws-s3' imported from /home/gmn/projects/examples/example/build/server/chunks/3-bb04b102.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mock-aws-s3' imported from /home/gmn/projects/examples/example/build/server/chunks/3-bb04b102.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mock-aws-s3' imported from /home/gmn/projects/examples/example/build/server/chunks/3-bb04b102.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'mock-aws-s3' imported from /home/gmn/projects/examples/example/build/server/chunks/3-bb04b102.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:889:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:938:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36)
```

Comment: In my case it was caused by the package `bcrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

It simply has to do with what you have in `devDependencies` and `dependencies`. You need to move Mongo and Aws to `dependencies`.